# How were people reunited (Gen 11) after being divided by language (Gen 10)?

Tags: genesis, contradiction, chronology

Genesis recorded that Noah had three sons. Probably they were living among their own people and must be spoke one language but then how Noah's sons were divided into seperate community according to their languages right after the flood (Gen 10)?

Again in chapter 11 mentioned that the whole earth had one language and some words (11:1)?

Comment: You will find your answer in the immediate verses 3-9, you will read in verse 6 that God confused their language.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a chronological telling of the story.  Genesis 10 is giving specific details on the lineage and Genesis 11 is an additional story that fits in the middle of Genesis 10.

Gen 10:  Now these are the records of the generations of Shem, Ham, and Japheth, the sons of Noah; and sons were born to them after the flood.

Gen 11:  Now the whole earth used the same language and the same words.

We see this same pattern in the first 3 chapters of Genesis.

Comment: Sir,  i agreed in your saying, Noah had sons after the flood too but if am not mistaken the first three sons were born before flood.

Comment: You are right.  3 sons born before the flood.  "Them" in Genesis 10:1 refers to the sons born to these 3 after the flood.

Answer (score 1):

Genesis 10, called the Table of Nations, gives a long list of the various descendants of Noah and his sons. Interpreters debate whether we are to understand the various nations as actually being named after Noah's grandsons and great-grandsons or whether they're just representative, but as a whole that's what it indicates. Chapter 10 is not a narrative, it is a genealogy, like chapter 5 before it, and chapter 11:10-32 after it, and more after that.

Chapter 11:1-9, the story of the tower of Babel, is a narrative explaining how the languages were confused and the descendants of Noah dispersed.

Each genealogical section in Genesis is in order, as are all its narrative sections, however these different genres overlap in what they cover.

Comment: ([Adapted from an older answer of mine on Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/61536/6071).)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

The descendants of Shem, Ham and Japheth once lived in different places across the world (or most likely, in the first few generations, different parts of the Middle East).

But in Genesis 11, a coalition  of Shemites (or Semites), Hamites and Japhethites sinisterly planned to settle east to create the Tower of Babel. With this tower, they could defy God and reject His laws, and ultimately, establish a kingdom united with one language. In other words, the ancient version of the NWO.

Then God saw that and **as punishment**, God confused their languages so that their plans to build the Tower of Babel failed from the beginning. They could try if they wanted to. Haven't they asked the people how they could travel to Neverland? Well that question is invalid because Neverland doesn't exist in the first place.

People need to read their Bibles more carefully and realise that this is just God's wrath against sin, just like any other. Framing the Tower of Babel as simply an origin story of different languages is a bit too simplistic.

Having one group of people sharing one language does not preclude them from previously having different languages just like how the one world government of the Antichrist does not preclude different governments pertaining to different nations from previously existing.